# What is throughput of ESP8266 NodeMCU

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu

I am comparing wireless technologies such as Zigbee and WiFi. 
I bought Zigbee module which has bandwidth of 256kbps but actual throughput is less than 30kbps. 
Similarly ESP8266 promises 1Mbps. But I don't know what throughput I am going to get.
Has anyone checked throughput of ESP8266 NodeMCU ?

Answer (score 1):

One of Espressif's staff posted a response to a similar question [here](http://bbs.espressif.com/viewtopic.php?t=2187) regarding throughput on the ESP8266 in AT bridge mode:

> TCP Throughput: AT TCP passthrough    Tx 303 Kbps; Rx 302Kbps @ baudrate 420000
>   UDP Throughput: AT UDP passthrough  Tx 250 Kbps; Rx 250 Kbps @ baudrate 420000